# drop down in javascript containing values from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

here is my code that creates a new row in the table on click of a button. The row has a drop down list. i want to fetch the options in the drop down list from a database. i can do that in html for a static drop down. how should i append that code in this script. Any help would be appreciated.
Javascript :

function addRow(tableID) {

```
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element0 = document.createElement("input");
        element0.type = "checkbox";
        element0.name="chkbox[]";
        element0.className="checkbox";
        cell1.appendChild(element0);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML = "<select name='projects[]' ><option value='m'>M</option><option value='c'>C</option><option value='s'>S</option><option value='l'>L</option><option value='n'>N</option><option value='i'>I</option><option value='t'>T</option><option value='other'>Other&hellip;</option></select>";
```

php code:-

```
 <?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from project");

echo '<select name="projects[0]">';


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['project_name'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call to get the database values in your javascript function.
This ajax response can be used to append the values to the dropdown.

In your case, as there is no inputs to query, no data need to be passed in the ajax call. Just make a call to the function with query and get back the result.

You can also make the response to a json response , so that it can be handled in javascript more efficiently.

Comment: thank you for your quick response!! a lil more detail would be helpful. how to append the ajax response ?

Comment: if we are passing the response as json in ajax. then, eval function can be used to extract each value and it can be directly appended to the drop down options.  See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp for more details on integrating ajax in your page

Comment: hey thanks i could finally do it.. the ajax code works well. but json response did not work so i had to use echo statement.